# Why is destination, flight level, and mach number needed in an oceanic clearance?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airline-operations

When getting an oceanic clearance. The aircraft must announce thier destination airport, their intended flight level, and intended mach cruise speed. Why are these necessary?

Comment: Because of the hundreds of other aircraft all in the same airspace?

Comment: Would you provide the source your question refers to? Thanks

Comment: @757toga This was the original article I read. But after reading deeper I started to understand more. https://skybrary.aero/articles/north-atlantic-operations-atc-clearance#:~:text=There%20are%20three%20elements%20to,or%20following%20a%20random%20route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destination, altitude, and speed are essential elements of any flight plan whether VFR, IFR, or Oceanic.

ATC needs this information to ensure proper spacing and sequencing in the case of IFR and Oceanic, and Flight Service needs it for VFR plans in order to know when to launch search and rescue efforts if you are over due landing at your destination.

*(Because without these three basic pieces, what else might a flight **plan** consist of?)*

Comment: Let's not forget the route of flight. For an aircraft flying through my airspace, that's just as important (or more important if they are landing a long distance away) than the destination.

Comment: @RetiredATC, yes, but I wanted to limit my answer to just the elements the OP questioned.